# The implications of: $\sum ^\infty _{k=1} \frac{a_k}{n^k}=O(\frac 1 n)$

Tags: asymptotics

I am reading [this note](http://fs2.american.edu/baron/www/627/Handouts/Jackknife.pdf) on the Jackknife estimator, and I'm confused about this part:

> Suppose
> $$
> \sum ^\infty _{k=1} \frac{a_k}{n^k}=O(\frac 1 n),
> $$
> then
> $$
> \sum ^\infty _{k=1} a_k (\frac 1 {n^{k-1}}-\frac{1}{(n-1)^{k-1}}) 
> = \frac{a_2}{n^2} + O(\frac 1{n^3})
> $$

Why is this?

I know the definition of the big-O notation but that's pretty much all I know about it so a thorough explanation would be much appreciated. It would be nice too if someone could tell me where to read more about it.
Thank you!

Comment: Note that in your second equation, the first term of the series is $0.$

Comment: Yes. This is one of the only few things I know haha

Comment: And what about the second term hoho? Please do not just ask: edit your post to include your progress.

Comment: Sorry but this is my progress. I cannot proceed from here.

Comment: Include that the first term is $0,$ and work a little on the second term.

Comment: I do not know the [Jackknife estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackknife_resampling) nor statistics. I can see nowhere in the linked notes the hypothesis of your first equation.